# Hide Columns Except Date Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a code that hides several columns except for the range defined by two cells. This is the code:

```
For i = 1 To LastDate
    If DDS(1, i) = StartDate Then
        DDS.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        For j = i To LastDate
            If DDS(1, i) = EndDate Then
                i = j
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Else
        DDS.Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
```

Is there a way to improve this code?
Why am I getting an object error when trying to hide the column?

"DDS" is a Range reviously defined.

```
With ActiveSheet
    LastDate = .Cells("2", Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    DDS = Range(.Cells(2, 11), .Cells(56, LastDate))
End With
```

Thanks.

Comment: This line will error without a Set assuming DDS is a range `DDS = Range(.Cells(2, 11), .Cells(56, LastDate))`

Comment: And if DDS is not a range it does not of course have an `EntireColumn` property.

Comment: I see. I just saw that the code doesn't work.

Comment: Any ideas to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
With ActiveSheet
    LastDate = .Cells("2", Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    set DDS = .Range(.Cells(2, 11), .Cells(56, LastDate))
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Startdate and enddate, then hide all the columns and unhide the columns between start and end dates.

Edit to suite:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim fDate As Range
    Dim e As Range, s As Range, UnH As Range

    StartDate = Range("W2").Value
    EndDate = Range("X2").Value

    Set rng = Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
    Set s = rng.Find(StartDate, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set e = rng.Find(EndDate, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set UnH = Range(Cells(1, s.Column), Cells(1, e.Column))

    rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    UnH.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I really like your solution but my problem with it is that the dates are in merged cells and they have multiple columns under them. When excel is looking for a value in a merged cell it considers that only the first cell of the merged has the value (which annoys me very much).

Comment: You should not  use merged cells in ranges you intend to use vba with,

Comment: Ok, so how could I have this without merging the cells? I mean, they are multiple columns relative to a specific date

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this.

```
Sub test()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim DDS As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, LastDateCol As Long

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    With Ws
        LastDateCol = .Cells("2", Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set DDS = .Range(.Cells(2, 11), .Cells(56, LastDateCol))
    End With

    For i = 1 To DDS.Columns.Count
        If DDS.Item(1, i) = StartDate Then
            DDS.Item(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            For j = i To LastDate
                If DDS.Item(1, i) = EndDate Then
                    i = j
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Else
            DDS.Item(1, i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Is it intended that you loop only first row (`DDS(1, i)`)? 
 
You range is 55 rows `DDS = Range(.Cells(2, 11), .Cells(56, LastDate))`